# Haskell type checking and determinism

Tags: haskell, hindley-milner

According to the [Haskell 2010 language report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch1.html#x6-120001.3), its type checker is based on [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system). So consider a function `f` of this type,

```
f :: forall a. [a] -> Int
```

It could be the length function for instance. According to Hindley-Milner, `f []` type checks to `Int`. We can prove this by instantiating the type of `f` to `[Int] -> Int`, and the type of `[]` to `[Int]`, then conclude that the application `([Int] -> Int) [Int]` is of type `Int`.

In this proof, I chose to instantiate types `forall a. [a] -> Int` and `forall a. [a]` by substituting `Int` to `a`. I can substitute `Bool` instead, the proof works too. Isn't it strange in Hindley-Milner that we can apply a polymorphic type to another, without specifying which instances we use ?

More specifically, what in Haskell prevents me from using the type `a` in the implementation of `f` ? I could imagine that `f` is a function that equals `18` on any `[Bool]`, and equals the usual length function on all other types of lists. In this case, would `f []` be `18` or `0` ? The Haskell report says "the kernel is not formally specified", so it's hard to tell.

Comment: That's a great question. Note that your function `f` which behaves on `[Bool]` differently from on other list types `[a]` can not exist (i.e. can not be written in Haskell) because of _parametricity_. In Haskell there is no way to write `if a==Bool then ...` and have an unaltered signature `forall a. [a] -> Int`.

Comment: See my answer below. Parametricity can be a bit overwhelming at first, but you can start from the classical "theorems for free" paper by Wadler, which shows nice examples.

Comment: I don't have a perfect reference. Parametricity is sometimes affected by bottoms (`seq`, infinite recursion) but I recall that assuming functions strict one can still have a weaker form of parametricity. (Again, I can't provide a reference). To completely "break" parametricity, one can use `forall a. Typeable a => [a] -> Int` which allows `if a==Bool then ...` -- but here the type changes, so it is not really broken: we have a type for parametric polymorphism and another one for ad-hoc (non-parametric) polymorphism.

Comment: No, the extra `a` argument is not needed at all in Haskell. And even in Coq, you can't eliminate `(a : Type)` so there is no "if". In Coq you would need some argument to eliminate such as `forall (a : Type), typeable a -> list a -> int` where `typeable a` is suitably defined, e.g. with an inductive definition.

Comment: @chi Without the extra `a` the best I found is `f l = if typeOf l == typeOf ([True]) then 18 else length l`. But then `f []` crashes with a type error. Do you see an other way ?

Comment: `f []` becomes ambiguous since now `a` matters. Try `f ([] :: [Bool])` or `f ([] :: [Int])`.

Comment: You can also use `if typeOf (undefined :: a) == typeOf (undefined :: Bool)`. Personally, I often prefer `eqT` since it triggers GADT refinement, but that's another issue.

Comment: @chi I couldn't compile with `undefined :: a`, it says the famous `a` is unknown. Can you give the full implementation of `f` with it ?

Comment: Turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` and then `foo :: forall a. Typeable a => [a]->Int ; foo xs = if typeOf (undefined :: a) == ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During type inference, such type variables can indeed instantiated to any type. This may be seen as a highly non deterministic step.

GHC, for what it is worth, uses the internal `Any` type in such cases. For instance, compiling

```
{-# NOINLINE myLength #-}
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength = length

test :: Int
test = myLength []
```

results in the following Core:

```
-- RHS size: {terms: 3, types: 4, coercions: 0}
myLength [InlPrag=NOINLINE] :: forall a_aw2. [a_aw2] -> Int
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
myLength =
  \ (@ a_aP5) -> length @ [] Data.Foldable.$fFoldable[] @ a_aP5

-- RHS size: {terms: 2, types: 6, coercions: 0}
test :: Int
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
test = myLength @ GHC.Prim.Any (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Prim.Any)
```

where `GHC.Prim.Any` occurs in the last line.

Now, is that really not deterministic? Well, it does involve a kind of non deterministic step "in the middle" of the algorithm, but the final resulting (most general) type is `Int`, and deterministically so. It does not matter what type we choose for `a`, we always get type `Int` at the end.

Of course, getting the same type is not enough: we also want to get the same `Int` value. I conjecture that it can be proven that, given

```
f :: forall a. T a
g :: forall a. T a -> U
```

then

```
g @ V (f @ V) :: U
```

is the same value whatever type `V` is. This should be a consequence of [parametricity](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) applied to those polymorphic types.

Answer (score 3):

To follow-up on Chi's answer, here is the proof that `f []` cannot depend on the type instances of `f` and `[]`. According to Theorems for free (the last article [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html)),
for any types `a,a'` and any function `g :: a -> a'`, then

```
f_a = f_a' . map g
```

where `f_a` is the instantiation of `f` on type `a`, for example in Haskell

```
f_Bool :: [Bool] -> Int
f_Bool = f
```

Then if you evaluate the previous equality on `[]_a`, it yields `f_a []_a = f_a' []_a'`. In the case of the original question, `f_Int []_Int = f_Bool []_Bool`.

Some references for parametricity in Haskell would be useful too, because Haskell looks stronger than the polymorphic lambda calculus described in Walder's paper. In particular, this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity) says parametricity can be broken in Haskell by using the `seq` function.

The wiki page also says that my type-depending function exists (in other languages than Haskell), it is called [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism).

Comment: You can do ad-hoc polymorphism (and therefore write your type-dependent function) in Haskell, using a typeclass. If you do this, the type checker will force you to explicitly specify which type you're using for `a`.

Comment: @DarthFennec hum... That seems to contradict the parametricity equation above. Or the type of the function is not `forall a. [a] -> Int`. Can you give the exact example you're thinking of?

Comment: You're correct, sorry I wasn't clear; if you use a typeclass (let's call it `Foo`) to make a type-dependent function, then the type of the function must be `forall a. Foo a => [a] -> Int`. If we don't add the class constraint to `a`, then yes, parametricity dictates the function cannot be type-dependent.